# Form to upload and replace unmanaged file

Tags: forms, files, 9

I want to make a form where a user can upload a file that will be saved in a predefined path in the private filesystem, replacing whatever was there before.

E.g. the destination file path could be `'private://mymodule/config.yml'`.

The file, once uploaded, does not need to be a file entity, it can remain unmanaged. It just holds some global configuration or data.

Ideally there will be some validation of the file contents, before the destination file is overwritten.

### What I found so far

I have not really found a complete example for this, and it seems I need to use some non-obvious steps. It seems I need file_save_upload(), which is a relic from Drupal 7. But I could be wrong.

E.g. I found this [How can I upload and read an unmanaged file?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/300892/how-can-i-upload-and-read-an-unmanaged-file) but it is not really the same.

I might even answer this myself if I can figure it out :)

Comment: The linked example contains everything you need to know to build it yourself.

Comment: I am going to post an answer with a code example.

Answer (score 2):

Here we go.

### References

I did not come up with this myself, I just assembled ideas from elsewhere.

- [How can I upload and read an unmanaged file?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/300892/how-can-i-upload-and-read-an-unmanaged-file)

  - This points to this example: https://github.com/xurizaemon/csvimport/blob/8.x-1.x/src/Form/CSVimportForm.php
- In core there is `Drupal\system\Form\ThemeSettingsForm` with upload for logo and favicon. It uses an internal function `_file_save_upload_from_form()` which might be removed in a minor version, so we can't use that.
- I found [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QLUDogIWwpM) about private unmanaged files. I am sure this info is available elsewhere, but it was the first thing I found.

### Code example

In this example I make it about an image file instead of a config file.

#### Create entry in mymodule.routing.yml

```yml
mymodule.acme_logo_form:
  path: '/admin/config/acme-logo'
  defaults:
    _form: '\Drupal\mymodule\Form\AcmeLogoForm'
    _title: 'Replace ACME logo'
  requirements:
    # This permission needs to be defined somewhere.
    _permission: 'manage acme logo'
```

#### Create the form

```php
<?php

namespace Drupal\mymodule\Form;

use Drupal\Core\Extension\ExtensionPathResolver;
use Drupal\Core\File\FileSystemInterface;
use Drupal\Core\File\FileUrlGeneratorInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Drupal\file\Entity\File;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

/**
 * Form to upload a custom acme-logo.png file.
 */
class AcmeLogoForm extends FormBase {

  const CUSTOM_FILE_URI = 'private://path/to/acme-logo.png';

  /**
   * @var \Drupal\Core\File\FileUrlGeneratorInterface
   */
  private FileUrlGeneratorInterface $fileUrlGenerator;

  /**
   * @var \Drupal\Core\File\FileSystemInterface
   */
  private FileSystemInterface $fileSystem;

  /**
   * @var \Drupal\Core\Extension\ExtensionPathResolver
   */
  private ExtensionPathResolver $extensionPathResolver;

  /**
   * Constructor.
   *
   * @param \Drupal\Core\File\FileUrlGeneratorInterface $file_url_generator
   *   File url generator.
   * @param \Drupal\Core\File\FileSystemInterface $file_system
   *   File system.
   */
  public function __construct(
    // Depending on PHP version we could use constructor property promotion.
    FileUrlGeneratorInterface $file_url_generator,
    FileSystemInterface $file_system,
    ExtensionPathResolver $extension_path_resolver
  ) {
    $this->fileUrlGenerator = $file_url_generator;
    $this->fileSystem = $file_system;
    $this->extensionPathResolver = $extension_path_resolver;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public static function create(ContainerInterface $container) {
    return new static(
      $container->get('file_url_generator'),
      $container->get('file_system'),
      $container->get('extension.path.resolver')
    );
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getFormId() {
    return 'mymodule_acme_logo_form';
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

    $form['#_attributes'] = [
      'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data',
    ];

    // Show a link to the default file that is tracked in version control.
    $form['default_file_link'] = [
      'link' => [
        '#type' => 'link',
        '#url' => $this->fileUrlGenerator->generate($this->extensionPathResolver->getPath('module', 'mymodule') . '/acme-logo-default.png'),
        '#title' => 'default logo.png',
        '#attributes' => ['target' => '_blank'],
      ],
      '#theme_wrappers' => ['container'],
    ];

    // Show a download link for the custom file, if exists.
    if (is_file(self::CUSTOM_FILE_URI)) {
      $form['custom_file_link'] = [
        'link' => [
          '#type' => 'link',
          '#url' => $this->fileUrlGenerator->generate(self::CUSTOM_FILE_URI),
          '#title' => 'custom acme-logo.png',
          '#attributes' => ['target' => '_blank'],
        ],
        '#theme_wrappers' => ['container'],
      ];
    }

    $form['file'] = [
      '#title' => $this->t('New custom acme-logo.png'),
      '#type' => 'file',
    ];

    $form['submit'] = [
      '#type'  => 'submit',
      '#value' => $this->t('Upload'),
    ];

    return $form;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function validateForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state): void {
    parent::validateForm($form, $form_state);

    // Create a temporary file entity based on the file form element.
    // @todo file_save_upload() might soon be deprecated.
    // Unfortunately https://www.drupal.org/node/2244513 was closed without providing an alternative to file_save_upload().
    // @todo Catch errors from this operation.
    // @todo Find a way to avoid creating temporary file entities.
    $tmp_file_entity = file_save_upload(
      'file',
      [
        'file_validate_extensions' => ['png'],
      ],
      FALSE,
      0,
    );

    if (!$tmp_file_entity instanceof File) {
      $form_state->setErrorByName('file', t('Upload failed.'));
      return;
    }

    // @todo Validate file contents.

    // Keep the temporary file entity available for submit handler.
    $form_state->setValue('tmp_file', $tmp_file_entity);
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $values = $form_state->getValues();

    /** @var \Drupal\file\Entity\File $tmp_file_entity */
    $tmp_file_entity = $values['tmp_file'];

    // Create parent directory, if it does not exist.
    // @todo Handle errors from this operation.
    $directory = dirname(self::CUSTOM_FILE_URI, 2);
    $this->fileSystem->prepareDirectory(
      $directory,
      FileSystemInterface::CREATE_DIRECTORY | FileSystemInterface::MODIFY_PERMISSIONS);

    // Copy the file as an unmanaged file in the private filesystem.
    // @todo Handle errors from this operation.
    $this->fileSystem->copy(
      $tmp_file_entity->getFileUri(),
      self::CUSTOM_FILE_URI,
      FileSystemInterface::EXISTS_REPLACE);
  }

}
```

#### Allow download access

Because this is in private filesystem, we need to grant download access explicitly.

```php
/**
 * Implements hook_file_download().
 */
function mymodule_file_download(string $uri) {
  if ($uri !== AcmeLogoForm::CUSTOM_FILE_URI) {
    // This is not the file we care about.
    return NULL;
  }
  if (!\Drupal::currentUser()->hasPermission('view acme logo')) {
    // No access.
    return -1;
  }
  // Set some headers to tell Drupal that access is granted.
  return [
    'Content-Type' => 'image/png',
  ];
}
```

### Notes

The `file_save_upload()` always creates temporary file entities that "pollute" the database.

The same effect occurs when uploading logos or favicons in the core theme settings.

The `file_managed` database tables will fill up with entries for temporary files.

This seems to be just how it works, until a replacement for or alternative to `file_save_upload()` is found.

Perhaps `Drupal\file\Upload\FileUploadHandler` could be used directly, but this also creates file entities afaik.